# Support for Array Comprehension in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, intellisense, list-comprehension, ecmascript-harmony

I've been reading up on the newer features of Javascript and noticed the Array Comprehension stuff.  I've tried this in my current project, but it seems Visual Studio doesn't like the syntax.  Am I doing it wrong?

```
var destArray = [{propOne: val, propTwo:val} for (val of sourceArray)];
```

Comment: VS is about 5 years behind javascript in the wild; just wait ;)

Comment: @dandavis: I don't think array comprehensions are exactly "in the wild". In fact, does *any* JS engine that's in actual use support them yet?

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen: i played with them years ago in firefox2: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.7#Array_comprehensions_(Merge_into_Array_comprehensions) so yeah, VS just needs to catch up with firefox v2.

Comment: @dandavis: VS needs to catch up with some obscure feature one specific JavaScript engine used mainly by one browser supports? I don't think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in fact part of the upcoming ES2016 specification, not ECMAScript 5 (your question was originally tagged with [ecmascript-5](/questions/tagged/ecmascript-5)).

According to [this](https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features#comprehensions) and the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Array_comprehensions), you actually need to place the `for` section at the beginning, not the end:

```
var destArray = [ for (val of sourceArray) { propOne: val, propTwo: val } ];
```

Just like other languages such as Python, you can also include multiple for loops and if statements:

```
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
var even = [ for (val of numbers) if (val % 2 === 0) val ];
```

Note that most text editors and IDEs don't support syntax highlighting for these new language features yet, so highlighting/colouring may look odd until more support comes in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the note.  It seems the syntax you suggest isn't understood by Chrome, either, so I suppose there's some waiting to do before I can even use this language feature at all.

Comment: Yes, it's not currently implemented in browsers yet, though some other sections of ES6 have already been implemented.